# Rally Authentication issue in Getting results

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, rally

I am using asp.net MVC application and consuming Rally web API for integration. I want fetch the data from rally site.

### in Login Controller

```
            RallyRestApi restApi = new RallyRestApi(webServiceVersion: "v2.0");
            dynamic authenticateUser=restApi.Authenticate(usr.UserName, usr.Password, "https://rally1.rallydev.com/", allowSSO: false);
            dynamic objUserName;
            if (authenticateUser.ToString().ToLower() == "authenticated")
            {
                Session["Username"] = usr.UserName;
                Session["Password"] = usr.Password;                   
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(usr.UserName, true);
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(usr.Password, true);
                objUserName = restApi.GetCurrentUser();
                Session["DisplayName"] = objUserName["DisplayName"];
                return RedirectToAction("Home", "PortfolioItem");
            }
```

Here Authentication is successful. But as per my research, if we want to fetch data every time,  I think we need to pass user authentication details like below:

```
      CreateResult createResult = restApi.Create("defect", toCreate); // need to get with same restApi object or authentication details


      OperationResult updateResult = restApi.Update(createResult.Reference, toUpdate);

      //Get the item
      DynamicJsonObject item = restApi.GetByReference(createResult.Reference);// need to get with same restApi object or authentication details

      //Query for items
      Request request = new Request("defect");
      request.Fetch = new List<string>() { "Name", "Description", "FormattedID" };
      request.Query = new Query("Name", Query.Operator.Equals, "My Defect");
      QueryResult queryResult = restApi.Query(request); // need to get with same restApi object or authentication details
```

Like above, is it if we need to fetch anything, we need to authenticate first and every time? please clarify on this.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to authenticate once for each instance of RallyRestApi you create.  In general it is better to create one, use it, and then dispose of it rather than creating it once and then keeping it around in session forever.

Comment: I have placed the creating object in separate  class and in a constructor to avoid creating object everytime, But where I have to dispose it , in destructor ?