# Unable to cast object of type 'Rally.RestApi.RallyRestApi' to type 'System.IDisposable'

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, rally

I am using Rally Web API, I am authenticating Rally web API class below :

```
 public class FetchRally
  {
    RallyRestApi restApi;
    public FetchRally()
    {
        restApi = new RallyRestApi(webServiceVersion: "v2.0");
        restApi.Authenticate(HttpContext.Current.Session["Username"].ToString(), HttpContext.Current.Session["Password"].ToString(), "https://rally1.rallydev.com/", allowSSO: false);
    }

    public void GetMethod(){
       try{
        //Do Something
        }
       catch{}
       finally
        {
            ((IDisposable)restApi).Dispose(); // Getting error
        }
       }

    }
```

I want to dispose  or kill the object after method code execution, but in run time facing below error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'Rally.RestApi.RallyRestApi' to type 'System.IDisposable'.

Can anyone please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

You can't cast `RallyRestApi` to `IDisposable` because this class doesn't implement `IDisposable` interface - [RallyRestApi Class](http://rallytools.github.io/RallyRestToolkitFor.NET/html/a256a81e-6dba-bafb-e2df-d1adbe1a36d2.htm#!)

If you don't need this object after method executes:

```
finally
{
    restApi = null;
}
```

And garbage collector will destroy this object during next Garbage Collection if you don't have any other references to this object.

Comment: Then what would be the solution to destroy or release object? can you please suggest me. @Roma

Comment: @DotNetDeveloper, why do you need to call `Dispose()`. If this class doesn't use unmanaged resources and is not very huge  you don't need to call `Dispose()`. You can simply delete `finally` block if you don't do anything else.

Comment: Please refer this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42346253/rally-authentication-issue-in-getting-results . As per answer, I need to dispose the object.

Comment: @DotNetDeveloper, but you can't call `Dispose()` for object of this type. In that answer "dispose" may mean that you should set it to null: `restApi = null` - so you will delete all references to this object and it will be deleted on next Garbage Collection.